# Ambient Light Sensor

Tags: brightness

I using the HP nc6400 notebook. The display shows dim whenever the light sensor is on, but when I disable the light sensor option, the brightness is satisfactory but it is blinking. How do I cure that the display not blinking while the ambient light sensor is option is disabled and while there is no blinking when the ambient light sensor option enabled?